# Download Github Release with version tag

Tags: github, github-release

I have a Github release and I want to download the latest assests with the version tag.

I want to save the .exe file with version include but this will prevent me from downloading the latest release with a single same link every time.

[image: Release details]

I want to download the latest released Outdated-Snake.Setup.exe with the tag name (i.e Outdated-Snake.Setup.v2.0.1.exe something like this)

Can I do it with editing the link somehow or do I have to change the .exe file name somehow?   What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this when you're downloading via the web interface unless you use your browser's Save As functionality.

However, if you're downloading with `curl` from the command line, you can use the `-o` option to specify a file name that you'd like to use to save the file.  For example, if I wanted to download the latest Git LFS Windows installer to `foo.exe`, I could do this:

```
$ curl -L -o foo.exe \
  https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases/download/v2.13.3/git-lfs-windows-v2.13.3.exe
```

You can also write a small shell function to extract the tag from the URL (say, with sed's `s` command) and then use that to name the file.  For example, with the Git LFS file I mentioned above, you could do something like this:

```
download () {
    url="$1"
    version=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's!^.*/\(v[0-9]*\.[0-9\]*\.[0-9]*\)/.*$!\1!')
    curl -L -o foo-$version.exe "$url"
}
```

Since you haven't linked to the repository from which you're trying to download, I can't provide an example that will work with that specific repository, but you can make appropriate adjustments to suit your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, I am using 'a' tag in html to point that link.  [Outdated-Snake-Desktop](https://github.com/OutdatedGuy/Outdated-Snake-Desktop) is the repository. 
 The game where 'a' tag is used is [Outdated-Snake](https://outdated-snake.herokuapp.com)

Comment: Then you're looking for something that your browser can do automatically, which depends on your browser.  GitHub doesn't offer a native way to do this any more than any other website does.